# SQL statement for getting an empty record set?

Tags: sql

Assume you have a database table named Documents and the primary key field is DocumentsId.  Which of these statements is the "best practice", "fewest resources", "fastest".

```
select * from Documents where DocumentsId Is Null
select * from Documents where 1 = 2
select top 0 * from Documents
```

Comment: This sounds like a really theorical question... What is the background behind it?

Comment: All of them are relatively fast. It really depends on what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: I was just wondering from a SQL perspective which was best practice.  It is something that is occasionally used.